# JQuery AutoComplete not displaying

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, jquery-ui

I have used JQuery UI autocomplete to cut down on the list of parts I have to display in a drop down, I am also using json to pass the list of parts back but I am failing to see the results, I am sure this is to do with my limited understanding of JQuery's Map function.

I have the following json

```
{"parts":[{"partNumber":"654356"},{"partNumber":"654348"},{"partNumber":"654355-6"},{"partNumber":"654355"},{"partNumber":"654357"},{"partNumber":"654357-6"},{"partNumber":"654348-6"}]}
```

which on [JSONLint](http://jsonlint.com/) is validated correct

I have viewed the post and response utilising Firebug and seen them to be correct but my auto complete does not seem to display, the closest I have got it to doing so, was when I displayed the entire JSON string with each character having a new line.

here is my JS

```
$('.partsTextBox').autocomplete({
    minLength: 3,
    source: function(request, response) {
        $.ajax({
            url: './PartSearch.ashx',
            data: $('.partsTextBox').serialize(),
            datatype: 'JSON',
            type: 'POST',
            success: function(data) {
                response($.map(data, function(item) {
                    return { label: item.partNumber }
                }))
            }
        });
    },

    select: function(e) {
        ptb.value = e;
    }
});
```

Any help anyone can give would be much appreciated. Have edited to include help given by soderslatt

Comment: i can't see if you are using the callback, can you tell me? my eyes are a bit sore

Comment: sorry I'm not sure what you mean, if you mean am I using the data retrieved then I believe i am in the success function.

Comment: Does is show any error in *Firebug console*?
Also does `response` function resolve properly?

Comment: no error , but an empty display at the moment, in that a box is diosplayed with no contents. Response appears to have completed and exited.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

jquery autocomplete plugin format out have to

{"query":"your_query","suggestions":["suggestions_1","suggestions_2"],"data":[your_data]}}

and use autocomplete that

```
$('#your_input').autocomplete({
    minChars: 2
    , serviceUrl: './PartSearch.ashx'
    , deferRequestBy: 50
    , noCache: true
    , params: { }
    , onSelect: function(value, data) {

    }
    , ajaxCallBack: function() {
            response($.map(data, function(item) {
                return { label: item.partNumber}
            }))
    }
});
```

Comment: 2 questions, are you saying that i need to change the format of my JSON? and i can't find the options you have provided within the documentation for autocomplete (I may have missed something here)?

Comment: hmm maybe other version of autocomplete,
i use this
http://www.devbridge.com/projects/autocomplete/jquery/

Comment: that explains it I use JQuery UI autocomplete, I have updated origibnal question to specify this, and I am looking into the plugin you use.

Comment: see example http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/#remote,
json format have to

[ { "id": "Coccothraustes coccothraustes", "label": "Hawfinch", "value": "Hawfinch" }, { "id": "Accipiter gentilis", "label": "Northern Goshawk", "value": "Northern Goshawk" }, { "id": "Accipiter nisus", "label": "Eurasian Sparrow Hawk", "value": "Eurasian Sparrow Hawk" }, { "id": "Surnia ulula", "label": "Northern Hawk Owl", "value": "Northern Hawk Owl" } ]

Comment: I have updated my JSON format to the following 
[{"partNumber":"654356"},{"partNumber":"654348"},{"partNumber":"654355-6"},{"partNumber":"654355"},{"partNumber":"654357"},{"partNumber":"654357-6"},{"partNumber":"654348-6"}] but still only getting a single character per line output

Comment: i think have to like this

[ { "id": "654356", "label": "654356", "value": "654356" }, { "id": "654348", "label": "654348", "value": "654348" }]
and so on, 
plugin parse response.label properties

Comment: Thanks for your persistence it's very much appreciated, but the problem I have is when replacing the variable as defined in the jsfiddle script with an ajax call then the data does not display if I hardcode it works, but as soon as I step over to AJAX it stops working?

Comment: of course,

plugin wait right json format and parse label property,

you have to build on server side array like this,

    $out = array(
        array('id' => '1', 'label' => 'Your first Part_namber', 'value' => 'Your first Part_namber'),
        array('id' => '2', 'label' => 'Your second Part_namber', 'value' => 'Your second Part_namber'),
    );

and then echo json_encode($out) for PHP or your server side language json encode function

Comment: yes this is what I am doing './PartSearch.ashx' here and retuning the JSON through the C# DataContractJsonSerializer class, I ma very confused as to why it will not work with AJAX

Comment: thanks for all your help yesterday I have figured out the last part I had to parse the json into an array I was just being dumb on this point "var parts = $.parseJSON(data);" fixed the problem thanks again have marked and pointed :)

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure, but shouldn't parts.part be an array ?

http://jsfiddle.net/jfTVL/3/

Comment: I UPsdated your code there with a snippet of my json like so

$(function()  {         
    var parts= [{"partNumber":"654356"},{"partNumber":"654348"},{"partNumber":"654355-6"},{"partNumber":"654355"},{"partNumber":"654357"},{"partNumber":"654357-6"},{"partNumber":"654348-6"}];
    $( "#tags" ).autocomplete({
        source: function( request, response ) {
            response($.map(parts.part, function(item) {
                return { label: item.partNumber}
            }))
         }
     });     
});

still no output :(

Comment: in my first jsfiddle I changed it to an array, new jsfiddle with your new structure as mentioned above,http://jsfiddle.net/jfTVL/6/

Comment: I see that your jsfiddle works and I cannot see what I am doing with the returned data from my ajax query that is different to your response? I am seeing the structure come backand be passed into the response function but item still only contains a suingle character array really confused now as your example works fine?

Comment: wondering if the ajax part of my script is not passing the data into the map function correctly, wondering if the json is being parsed into a char array, this would explain why each line was just one character

Answer (score 1):

From the [jQuery autocomplete page](http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/):

> The local data can be a simple Array of Strings, or it contains Objects for each item in the array, with either a label or value property or both. The label property is displayed in the suggestion menu. The value will be inserted into the input element after the user selected something from the menu. If just one property is specified, it will be used for both, eg. if you provide only value-properties, the value will also be used as the label.

Which means that if you use "value" instead of "partNumber", you should get want you want.